# A Christian that believe in one God and gives him no image. What kind of Christian is that?

Tags: christology, non-trinitarian

I always believed in One God, with no image( which for me means no mental image of something). 
Jesus Christ is a prophet from God. I was taught in this way. I was in a Catholic College and I never heard from a priest that Jesus Christ is God. What type of Christian am I?

I ask this because many non-Christians tend to believe that all Christians believe that the son of Mary is God - I'm not talking about trinity here because as I said, I believe in One God.

Comment: What does “with no image” mean ?  Catholics certainly do believe in the trinity and teach that Jesus is God

Comment: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/24176/23657. This related question may be helpful

Comment: I think many Christians (Protestant, Catholic, and Orthodox, as understood from my Protestant background) would say that Jesus is God is an essential doctrine, so not believing that would make you not a Christian. And all Christians certainly believe in One God. But as the link Kris posted says, it would be a non-Trinitarian or likely Unitarian view. Also like Kris mentioned, what does "with no image" mean?

Comment: Kris, for me image means mental image of something.

Comment: @AlexStrasser  Regarding trinity, I know christians that believe, do not believe, and question about trinity, even constant-practicers, so in my cultural perspective they are still christians - these that were born with a bible near, they are free to considering them-selfs christians even if they are non-practicers and believe in one God (or lastly in a ethnic origins sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unitarianism** (from Latin *unitas* "unity, oneness", from *unus* "one") - *Thanks @DJClayworth*

- Is a Christian theological movement named for its belief that the **God in Christianity is one person**
- Believe that Jesus was inspired by God in his moral teachings, and he is a savior, but he was not a deity or God incarnate.
- Unitarians place emphasis on the ultimate role of reason in interpreting sacred scriptures
- Other possible designation for this is Unorthodox. (*Thanks @Lesley*)

(Source: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitarianism) )

Its worth to mention [**Iconoclasm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconoclasm). *(Thanks @PeterTurner)* this characteristic its important to mention and related:

Within Christianity, **iconoclasm** has generally been motivated by those who adopt a **literal interpretation of the Ten Commandments**, **which forbid the making and worshiping of "graven images or any likeness of anything"**.

I think Unitarian Christian its the best modern answer. And in a Catholic sense, some can consider this type of Christian as Unorthodox, even if some can have different concepts about God (trinity for example). For a long time I was a constant practicer and I always believed in One God with no image and in the [Commandments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten_Commandments#Christianity) -  This conceptualization about Unitarian Christianity belief is similar to: (@Thanks Anne)

- Jehovah's witnesses
- Mormons
- (Quran) Muslims
- (Torah) Jews

I have nothing more than to respect others Christians beliefs, taking in consideration that the apparent majority of people that are Christians believe in the pure [Orthodox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Orthodox_Church) sense.

Answer (score 3):

**Virtually all Christians consider Jesus to be the image of God** because of this passage in Colossians 1:15-16

> The Son is the image of the invisible God, the firstborn over all creation. For in him all things were created: things in heaven and on earth, visible and invisible, whether thrones or powers or rulers or authorities; all things have been created through him and for him.

If you are concerned with the question of whether Jesus is actually God, rather than whether he is merely the image of God, then the word you are looking for is probably **'Unitarian'**. Unitarians believe that Jesus is the best and ultimate prophet and messenger of God, but not actually God. There are other kinds of groups too, including 'Christadelphians'. If you want more specific information you would have to tell us more about what you believe. Unitarians and Christadelphians consider Jesus to be the image of God, for the reasons I said above.

If your Catholic priest never said at any time that Jesus Christ is God, then he either presumed you already knew that or, if you were of a different faith, didn't want to offend you by contradicting your faith. He almost certainly believed it himself.

Comment: Note though that even Unitarians would acknowledge some sense of Jesus being the image of God, as Colossians 1:15 says, and because all humans are made in his image!

Comment: curiousdanni See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitarianism). "Unitarian Christians, therefore, believe that Jesus was inspired by God in his moral teachings, and he is a savior, but he was not a deity or God incarnate. (...) " So, at least, not all of them acknowledge that.

Comment: @Bcloney That doesn't mean they don't believe Jesus is the image of God.

Comment: If I might add some advice, it's commonly agreed that Jesus intended his followers to live the Christian life as part of community - or at least not alone. I would strongly suggest finding other Christians to spend time with and identify with. This would also sort out the question of what label you want to apply to yourself - you can use the same label they do.

Comment: Exodus does not say "God has no image". It is a command "You will make no image", talking to the Israelites. Jesus can be the "image of God" because he was not made by the Israelites, so that doesn't contradict the command. The Bible (the foundation book of Christianity) specifically says Jesus is the image of God. If you want to understand more about this you might like to talk to Christian leader where you are.

Comment: I can assume that Jesus is the founder of Christianity, but I'll never assume that Christianity was founded by the existence of the Bible. We share the same Book, the same race, but not the same opinion. I think it's potentially an infinite discussion, because opinion divergencies between "Christians" are related with all the schisms that Christianity and Judaism had in its history.

Comment: I wonder if you don't accept the Bible then why is it a problem for you that Jesus is the image of God? It's only because it is written in the Bible that Christians think there shouldn't be images. Jesus himself never said that there shouldn't be images of God. And again, I wonder what other Christians you know say about this?

Comment: For me giving God an image is not different from worshiping an idol, associating 3 things to God I consider that something near Polytheism. I think Regarding the New and Last Testament, i can explain with 3 of the 10 Commandments  "Thou shalt not take the name of the Lord thy God in vain" ;  Thou shalt have no other gods before me;  Thou shalt not make unto thee any graven image - You can't say that I don't fully accept the Bible, or even some of God [Commandments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten_Commandments#Christianity).

Comment: You did actually say you didn't believe the Bible when the Bible says Jesus is the image of God (Colossians 1:15). However this has really got outside the boundaries of the question. If you want to follow up, I have created [a chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87194/chat-about-images) to talk about it more.

Answer (score 0):

That would make you Unorthodox, i.e., not pertaining to either Catholic or Protestant orthodox Christianity.  Because God is Spirit, it is impossible to give Him any image.  However, Trinitarian Christians acknowledge that there is only the One Being of God, but within the Godhead subsist the three persons of Father, Son and Holy Spirit.  Not three Gods, however.

Orthodox Christians also believe that Jesus was more than just a man, a prophet.  The Christian Bible tells us that before Jesus came to earth to be born and dwell with us, he was with God, in the beginning as the eternal and uncreated Word (or Logos) of God.  The Christian Bible also tells us that Jesus died, was resurrected and returned to heaven from whence he came.

Looking at your profile, it seems likely that you are a Muslim.  That might explain why you do not give God any image and why you believe that Jesus is only a man, a prophet from God.  If I am wrong, I will apologise.

Comment: Please accept my unreserved apology for drawing a wrong conclusion. I'm glad DJ Clayworth provided you with an insightful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may be an Iconoclast.  The reason that there are so many pictures of God and Jesus and the Holy Spirit in Christian churches is because we believe that when the Second Person of the Trinity (Jesus) took on human flesh in the Incarnation that He made a real "Image" of himself in human history.  Therefore depictions of Him are licit because He made a depiction of Himself.

[Iconoclasm](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/07620a.htm) was an overreaction to image worshipping which resulted in the smashing of all depictions of God (Father, Son and Holy Spirit) and all other holy pictures, even relics of the saints.

There's no real sect you can join to be with your iconsclastic brothers and sisters (and any attempt to practice what they preach would hopefully be against hate crime laws). Catholics, Orthodox and most Protestants are not Iconoclasts, although Protestants are probably closest.

- Catholics pretty much embrace every tasteful depiction of God,
- Orthodox prefer icons and
- Protestants pretty much loath everything except smiling or knocking pictures of Jesus as Papist nonsense.  But they like relics less than iconoclasts because they don't believe in the Communion of Saints in the same way Catholics and Orthodox do.

---

Basically, iconoclasm, wasn't necessarily about a hatred for art, but an exaggerated reaction against the doctrine that allowed the production of the art (i.e. the Incarnation).  [The Incarnation](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/07706b.htm) is central to all Christianity (and by extension all human history) so it's probably worth finding out what it is and why it's important before defining what kind of Christian believes the things you're asking about.